# Cross compile hostapd for arm7

Tags: android, arm, cross-compiling

I'm cross compiling hostapd for allwinner a13 board by following command

```
export PATH=PATH:/path_to_toolchain
export CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
make
```

hostapd binary generated successfully but when I execute hostapd in board then it gives 
"/system/bin/sh: hostapd: No such file or directory"

```
adb push hostpad /system/bin/
root@android:/ # chmod 777 /system/bin/hostapd
root@android:/ # hostapd
/system/bin/sh: hostapd: No such file or directory
```

So how to resolve this issue?

Comment: after u have compiled the hostapd u will get a binary right, type this command "file hostapd"
and verify if the binary is compiled for arm.
sometimes we may result in unsuccessful compilation to the target device.

Answer (score 0):

What toolchain are you using? You should use the same NDK toolchain as was used for your Android image, otherwise you'll have architecture/library mismatch.

Execute `file hostapd` and `file` on any binary in your Android image and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid above problem by

1) compile `statically`  or

2) compile your hostpd with same toolchain which you used in android build system.

`arm-none-linux-gnueabi` toolchain and `android toolchain` will having library mismatch.

Comment: I haven't build android system I'm just trying to cross compile hostapd for wifi hotspot issue, My question is how to know which toolchain used for compiling running android??

Comment: compile statically with arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc and run on target it ll work